# Jquery autocomplete, make categories clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, categories

I'm using jquery autocomplete with categories and i'd like to make categories clickable as items.

```
$(function() {
$("#js_autocomplete_ville").autocomplete({
    source: "ajax_villes.php",
    delay: 100,
    minLength: 1, 
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#js_searchform').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="villeid" value="' + ui.item.label + '">');
    },
    create: function() {
        $('.ui-autocomplete').addClass('ui-front');
        var currentDepartement = "";
        var currentVilleDepartement = "";
        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            if (item.dep_nom != currentDepartement) {
                ul.append("<li class='js_level1 ui-autocomplete-category' id='li_" + item.num_departement + "'>" + item.dep_nom + " (" + item.num_departement + ")</li>");
                currentDepartement = item.dep_nom;
            }
            var itemVilleDepartement = item.dep_nom + item.v_nom;
            if (itemVilleDepartement != currentVilleDepartement) {
                currentVilleDepartement = itemVilleDepartement;
                return $("<li class='js_level2' id='" + item.label + "'>")
                        .append('<a>' + item.value + '</a>')
                        .appendTo(ul);

            } else {
                return $("")
                        .append('')
                        .appendTo(ul);
            }
        };
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#js_autocomplete_ville").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    },
    // optional
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
    }
});});
```

I try to do some test in 'select' event but no results !
Is it possible ? Any ideas ?
Thanks for your help,
Willy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but as the items added are dynamic you need to use a delegated event handler attached to a non-changing ancestor element:

e.g. something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.js_level1', function(){
   alert(".js_level1 clicked!");
});
```

It works by listening for bubbled events, then applying the jQuery selector at event time, not *event-registration* time. This means the elements only need to be there when you click.

`document` is the default if you do not have a closer element you can select. Never use `'body'` for delegated events as styling can stop `body` responding to bubbled click events.

**Note:** *Without the code running (e.g. in a JSFiddle) I can't be more specific*

Comment: Thk for your help TrueBlueAussie, I thought that idea but I wondered if it was not possible to do so with autocomplete (for example with an option, or method, or events...). I 'll try and if I succeed I'll post the solution.

Comment: @William Rossier: It all comes down to what elements are visible in the DOM when the autocomplete is running (which you can access with delegated event handlers). Best view the DOM changes using the Chrome F12 DOM explorer and see what gets created on the fly. You can then target the correct elements. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution, thanks to TrueBlueAussie

```
$(document).on('click', '#ui-id-1 .js_level1', function() {
var inputValue = $(this).attr('id');
var inputLabel = $(this).text();
$("input[name='ville_id_moteur']").val(inputValue);
$("input[name='ville']").val(inputLabel);
$("#js_autocomplete_ville").autocomplete("close");
```

});

Bye,
William